# C# threading, thread not persistant

Tags: c#, multithreading

Morning all,

Using C# .NET 4.0 and Visual Studio 2012 Express.

I have a program that runs some SQL stored procedures, then opens and Access database and auto generates the reports then emails them.

I have it set on a date so it runs as soon as midnight comes.

The following is a code sample.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread myUltiThread = new Thread(GetCurrentDate);
    myUltiThread.Start();
}

private void GetCurrentDate()
{
    string myDate = "";
    myDate = DateTime.Today.Day.ToString();

    if(myDate == "7" && myDateToggle == false)
    {
        Task t = new Task(() => RunMonthBackUp());
        t.Start();
    }

    if (myDate == "8" && myDateToggle == true)
    {
        myDateToggle = false;
    }
}
```

So as you can see once the button is pressed my program then starts the thread, which uses the getdate method, this method checks if the date is correct.

if it is then it starts a task that runs the whole process.

My problem is that this is not happening, I believe its because the method is only running once. I have a feeling this is due to my lack of understanding working with threads (only ever deal with tasks usually).

Could someone point out to me where I am going wrong and how to get this set up properly?

Many thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thread will be terminated when `GetCurrentDate` method reaches the end. You should provide a loop in your method and check for the condition periodically. Or you can set a timer (`System.Threading.Timer`) to check periodically for the condition.

Here is the first way:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread myUltiThread = new Thread(GetCurrentDate);
    myUltiThread.IsBackground = true;
    myUltiThread.Start();
}

private void GetCurrentDate()
{
    while(true)
    {
        int = DateTime.Today.Day;

        if(myDate == 7 && myDateToggle == false)
        {
            Task t = new Task(() => RunMonthBackUp());
            t.Start();
        }

        if (myDate == 8 && myDateToggle == true)
        {
            myDateToggle = false;
        }

        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
}
```

I also made the thread a background thread, so you don't need to worry about terminating the thread. The thread will continue to function until the program exits.

Comment: you sire are a legend, why did i not think of a simple loop inside the method. may not be the cleanist solution but nice and simple almost no extra code +1 to you sir!

Comment: You may not want to check the date that often!  For this purpose, you would be better off with  a Forms.Timer to start off the backups.  To reduce waste, check the time/date every half hour, say, until the hour before the backup time arrives.  Then check every minute until the last couple of mins, then calculate how many ms left till midnight and set the timer one last time to that value.

Comment: @StevenSmith Oh! I forgot one thing. Please place a `Thread.Sleep(1)` in the loop. This way the thread doesn't eat the CPU. Thanks to @Martin.

Answer (score 1):

Your method only runs the once as you have no code to repeat the check for the time after it has completed.

You need to start a timer that activates once a day, and then call `GetCurrentDate` from that.

Or better still write the code as a simple program that just performs your tasks once and run it as a scheduled task.

Answer (score 1):

Why not doing it this way ?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew( () => GetCurrentDate() );
    }

    private void GetCurrentDate()
    {
        if ( DateTime.Today.Day == 7 && myDateToggle == false )
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew( () => RunMonthBackUp());
        }
        else if ( DateTime.Today.Day == 8 && myDateToggle == true )
        {
            myDateToggle = false;
        }
    }
```

If something else is wrong with this, it got to do with your strange "toggling"